# Application of HMM to model contest selection behaviour in fantasy sports

Tags: markov

I am working on a research project wherein i have to model contest selection behaviour as a function of immediate gain, immediate loss, cumulative gain, cumulative loss. The contest choices are 1,2,and 3. And 0 is a state where the participant did not play. I have the dataset for 60 participants with their contest choices and associated gain/loss across 33 matches. I eventually want to decode contest selection patterns based on values of gain and loss and link it to user interviews i have taken. I thought hidden Markov model shall be a good way to model this problem. Request your help in figuring out this research problem and how should I proceed with this in python.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.